# Why do my google results have a different look on Android?

Tags: google-chrome, android

Since some weeks the google results on my Android device look different than on my friends Android devices. I don't like the new look, so does anyone know where this might come from and how I can change it back?

[image: the new look of the result list: black - where are the blue links?]

Comment: Google has many times before changed the layout for a fraction of their users to test out the UI.  Often it's optional sometimes it's not if there isn't a link to go to the old style then it's not.  As to way google would do this that's not on topic.

Comment: Are you and them signed in, and using the same browser to view google too?

Comment: Yes. Signed in on both devices, using the same browser, even the same device model, and the same google domain. But the results look different.

Comment: Signing out does not change anything, and signing back in neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution but not the answer to "why":

- Signed out in Chrome
- Removed all browser data
- Signed in again

But still would really like to know where this came from.